# Merge two objects by a selector id

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays A, B with objects from the database. I want to merge the objects from array B into array A that have a relation: (A[n].id == B[n].a_id).

```js
const array_a = [
  {
    "id": 4,
    "status": 0,
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "status": 1,
  }
];

const array_b = [{
  active: 1,
  a_id: 5, // SELECTOR FOR MERGE
  created_at: '2022-11-05 20:29:29',
  firstname: 'user3',
  lastname: ''
}];
```

**Expected result:**

```js
const result = [
  {
    "id": 4,
    "status": 0,
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "status": 1,
    "active": 1,
    "user_id": 5,
    "created_at": '2022-11-05 20:29:29',
    "firstname": 'user3',
    "lastname:" ''
}
];
```

I tried this approach from another SO answer and got nowhere.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53462680/18066399 :-/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript merging objects by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480008/javascript-merging-objects-by-id)

Comment: or [Merge two array of objects based on a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849286/merge-two-array-of-objects-based-on-a-key)

Comment: *'I tried this approach from another SO answer and got nowhere.'* Show what you tried and where you're stuck. All of the answers here are covered in the duplicate you linked as well as those I flagged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make a dictionary to look up later as `dict ={}` where the key is `a_id` and the value is the whole object itself. then iterate through the second array and look for if there is something already in `dict` if it's then we need to get them by `dict[val.id]` and merge the values with the original object.

Learn about [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

### Trick:

As you said data come from a database so data can be bigger in size, So you may want to avoid loop nesting like inside `.map()` again another loop like `filter` `find` etc. Suppose your database returns `1000 items` per each so if you use nested algorithms in the worst case you need to perform **`1000*1000 = 1000000` steps which is slower :(**

```js
const array_a = [
  {
    "id": 4,
    "status": 0,
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "status": 1,
  }
];

const array_b = [{
  active: 1,
  a_id: 5, // SELECTOR FOR MERGE
  created_at: '2022-11-05 20:29:29',
  firstname: 'user3',
  lastname: ''
}];
      
      
  const dict = array_b.reduce((acc, val) => ({...acc, [val.a_id]: val}), {});
  const res = array_a.map(val=> {
    if(!dict[val.id]) return val; //If nothing in "dict" object by id we return original obj
    const mergedObj = {...val, ...dict[val.id]}; //Merge two objects
    delete Object.assign(mergedObj, {user_id: mergedObj.a_id})['a_id']; //create "user_id" by the value of "a_id"  and delete old key "a_id"
    return mergedObj;
  });
  console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const array_a = [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "status": 0,
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "status": 1,
    }
  ];
  
  const array_b = [{
    active: 1,
    a_id: 5, // SELECTOR FOR MERGE
    created_at: '2022-11-05 20:29:29',
    firstname: 'user3',
    lastname: ''
  }];


  const merged = array_a.map((item) => {
        const found = array_b.find((i) => i.a_id === item.id);
        return found ? { ...item, ...found } : item;
    });


console.log("merged",merged);
```

A simple way of doing it: while looping inside the **array_a**, we check if the **id** is available in **array_b** as **a_id**, and if it was, we merge the data.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this would be to use `map()` and `filter()`. I don't know how big your result arrays from the database are. Of course, my way may not be the most efficient. But then neither would the others. Maybe you could already solve the problem with your database structure!

```js
const array_a = [
  {
    "id": 4,
    "status": 0,
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "status": 1,
  }
];

const array_b = [{
  active: 1,
  a_id: 5, // SELECTOR FOR MERGE
  created_at: '2022-11-05 20:29:29',
  firstname: 'user3',
  lastname: ''
}];

const result = array_a.map(_a => {
  const n = array_b.filter(_b => _b._id == _a.id);
  return n.length ? {..._a, ...n[0]} : _a;
})

console.log(result)
```

### Update with shorter solution

Inspired by this answer, which I personally found good. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61670621/18066399

```js
const array_a = [
  {
    "id": 4,
    "status": 0,
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "status": 1,
  }
];

const array_b = [{
  active: 1,
  a_id: 5, // SELECTOR FOR MERGE
  created_at: '2022-11-05 20:29:29',
  firstname: 'user3',
  lastname: ''
}];

const result = array_a.map(_a => ({..._a, ...array_b.find(_b => _b.a_id === _a.id)}));

console.log(result)
```